# StackOverflowError when executing cypher queries through Neo4J REST API

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j version 3.0.7

I'm reading a list of edges from a dataset and I need to pass those edges batch-wise using the REST API.
I used the following query format to create multiple nodes (if they already don't exist) and their relationships in Neo4j through a single Cypher query via the REST API. I obtain the two vertices of an edge and the node properties are set according to the vertex IDs of those vertices.

```
{
  "query":
    "MATCH (n { name: 0 }), (m { name:1 })
    CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)
    WITH count(*) as dummy
    MATCH (n { name: 0 }), (m { name: 6309 })
    CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)"
}
```

This approach works correctly for a batch of 10 edges but when I try to send a batch of 1000 edges (nodes and their relationships) through a single Cypher query, I get a `StackOverflowError` exception. Is there a better approach to achieve this task?
Thank you for your help.

The error obtained from the response:

```
{
  "exception" : "StackOverflowError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.StackOverflowError",
  "stackTrace" : [ "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:151) ..."
}
```

Comment: If you use this approach to insert ~1000 nodes, you will get a huge Cypher query. The StackOverflowError might be a symptom of the parser failing on that query.

Comment: did my answer solve the problem? If so, can you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: i tried with the approach you mentioned but with that way it takes about 3 minutes to send a single edge so to send a batch of 1000 edges it takes hours. is there any other optimal approach than this way to send batches of edges with minimal time?

Comment: 3 minutes is quite a lot for inserting a single edge. Do you have lots of nodes (like millions) in your database? Anyways, you are using the `name` attribute for finding the nodes, which means it would be worth putting an index on this property. For example, if you have `Person` nodes, index them with `CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)` (this example is taken from the [Cypher reference card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/)) - it should make quite a difference in the performance of the query.

Comment: thank you very much :).. I was able to upload a batch of edges within seconds by creating an index on the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNWIND` to get a single query:

```
UNWIND [[0,1], [0,6309]] AS pair
MATCH (n {name: pair[0]}), (m {name: pair[1]})
CREATE (n)-[:X]->(m)
```

Insert your node pairs after `UNWIND` as a list of two-element lists. As the query uses the `name` property for finding the nodes, it is worth adding an index to it. For example, if you haven `Person` nodes, index them with:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

(See also the [Cypher reference card](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/).)